How to speed up SQLite update query?
UPDATE ITEMS
SET ID_SECTION = (SELECT B.ID_SECTION
                  FROM TT_ItemSection B
                  WHERE ITEMS.ID_ITEM = B.ID_ITEM 
                    AND B.IS_MAINSECTION = 'Y');

How can I speed up the execution of this query? It is taking so much time to execute (in SQLite).
I tried update from with joins but it doesn't work in SQLite.

Start with https://sqlite.org/cli.html#index_recommendations_sqlite_expert_
